# Why spike in query time despite similar number of rows examined?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, testing, indexing

I am going through the slow query log to try to determine why some of the queries behave erratically. For the sake of consistency, the queries are not cached and flushing was done to clear system cache before running the test. The query goes something like this:

```
SELECT P.id, P.name, P.lat, P.lng, P.price * E.rate AS 'ask' FROM Property P
 INNER JOIN Exchange E ON E.currency = P.currency
 WHERE P.floor_area >= k?
  AND P.closing_date >= CURDATE() // this and key_buffer_size=0 prevents caching
  AND P.type ='c'
  AND P.lat BETWEEN v? AND v?
  AND P.lng BETWEEN v? AND v?
  AND P.price * E.rate BETWEEN k? AND k?
 ORDER BY P.floor_area DESC LIMIT 100;
```

The `k?` are user defined **constant** values; `v?` are **variables** that change as user drag or zoom on a map. 100 results are pulled out from the table and sorted according to floor area in descending order.

A PRIMARY key on `id` and an INDEX on `floor_area` is set up only. No other index is created so that MySQL would consistently use `floor_area` as the only key. The query times and rows examined are recorded as follows:

```
query number              1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
user action on map     start   >    +    +    <    ^    +    >    v    +
time in seconds          138  0.21 0.43 32.3 0.12 0.12 36.3 4.33 0.33 2.00
rows examined ('000)      43    43   43   60   43   43  111  139  133  176
```

The query execution plan is as follows:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | range  | id_flA        | id_flA  | 3       | NULL               | 4223660 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | E     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | BuySell.P.currency |       1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
```

The test is being performed a few times and the results are quite consistent with the above. What could be the **reason(s) for the spike in query times** in query number 4 and number 7 and how do I bring it down?

**UPDATE:**

Results of removing `ORDER BY` as suggested by Digital Precision:

```
query number              1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
user action on map     start   >    +    +    <    ^    +    >    v    +
time in seconds          255  3.10 3.16 3.08 3.18 3.21 3.32 3.18 3.17 3.80
rows examined ('000)     131  131  131  131  136  136  136  136  136  157
```

The query execution plan is the same as above though it seems more like a table scan. Note that I am using **MyISAM** engine, version 5.5.14.

AS requested, below is schema:

```
| Property | CREATE TABLE `Property` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lat` decimal(6,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `lng` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `floor_area` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `currency` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `closing_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `name` char(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_flA` (`floor_area`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

| Exchange | CREATE TABLE `Exchange` (
  `currency` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(11,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`currency`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**2ND UPDATE:**

I thought it would be appropriate to post the non-default parameters in the `my.cnf` configuration file since two of the answerers are mentioning about the parameters:

```
max_heap_table_size = 1300M
key_buffer_size = 0
read_buffer_size = 1300M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1024M
sort_buffer_size = 1300M
```

I have 2GB of RAM on my test server.

Comment: You can try adding an index on `(type, closing_date)` or `(type, floor_area)` - assuming that they are in the same table (it's not obvious without the tables' details - please add them). This may help the query in general, not the spikes.

Comment: @ypercude: There are several more conditions in the `WHERE` columns. I agree that it would help, but to a small extent due to the range issue and the low cardinality of `type` column. Need to resolve the simple index problem before trying the composite index.

Comment: `type` may have low cardinality but the index to help it will depend on the compound cardinality of `(type, floor_area)`. If almost all your rows that are checked each time have `type='condominium'` then it won't help much. But it will help occasionally.

Comment: can you provide the where clause for 3, 4, 7 and 10. If there are other conditions in the where clause please include then all as it could be something you're otherwise overlooking.

Comment: @Seph: the only difference between the queries 1 to 10 are the lat lng variables defined as `v?`. The rest of the where conditions are user defined constants `c?`.

Comment: @BenHuh have you considered indexing `{floor_area, lat, lng}`? Seems that would be an ideal index candidate. Otherwise there's also `{floor_area, closing_date}`, if the restriction on closing_date is not there just to prevent caching

Comment: @Seph: If you consider `floor_area` as the volumes, `lat` as the parts and `lng` as the chapters of a book, then each volume would only contain one part, and each part would only contain one chapter. The second and third column of the composite index would not be useful at all.

Comment: @BenHuh - I do think lat and lng are good candidates for a compound key. In a database with 5 million rows, for properties, I'm guessing that roughly half the records will match the ">=" criteria for common values. This may explain the variation you're seeing - by changing the search area, the database has to re-query a LOT of records, and then order them.

Comment: @NevilleK: If you look at query 3 and 4, a zoom (+) action is performed, causing a reduction in the search area. Yet, the time taken increases from 0.43s to 32.3s. I can't possibly use composite index to cover all the where conditions as it would exceed the size of my database. `Using where` is inevitable and it would take longer time if index `(lat, lng)` is applied at initial view (based on testing). MySQL optimiser is not smart enough to decide when not to use the index.

Comment: @BenHuh, so you have tried this with an index on just lat, lng? It would be a far more selective index - reducing the total number of records to just a few hundred, rather than hundreds of thousands...

Comment: @NevilleK: I would go for spatial index instead of a composite on lat,lng. But that doesn't solve the spike in query time issue.

Comment: @BenHuh, I agree that a spatial index would be better. Have you tried it? My guess is that the spikes are caused by the underlying weirdness of database engines (not a hugely helpful hypothesis, I know) - for instance, on both 4 and 7, the number of records considered increases; perhaps the database engine is doing memory and/or disk management to accomodate this extra data. The best way to optimize the query is to reduce the number of records considered in the "where" clause; my assertion is that geography is more selective than floor size.

Comment: @NevilleK: I did tried, it only start to perform when zooming in-depth. It performs worse, otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I guess I figure out the reason of spikes. Here is how it goes :

First I created the tables and load some randomly generated data on it:

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE P.id, P.name, P.lat, P.lng, P.price * E.rate AS 'ask' 
FROM Property P
 INNER JOIN Exchange E ON E.currency = P.currency
 WHERE P.floor_area >= 2000
  AND P.closing_date >= CURDATE()
  AND P.type ='c'
  AND P.lat BETWEEN 12.00 AND 22.00
  AND P.lng BETWEEN 10.00 AND 20.00
  AND P.price BETWEEN 100 / E.rate AND 10000 / E.rate
 ORDER BY P.floor_area DESC LIMIT 100;
```

And here is the describe :

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | range | id_flA        | id_flA | 3       | NULL | 4559537 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | E     | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL   | NULL    | NULL |       6 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

it took between **3.5 ~ 3.9** sec every time I query the data (didn't make any difference which parameters I use). It didn't make sense so I researched [Using join buffer](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=18)

Then I wanted to try this query without "join buffer" so I inserted 1 more random data to Exchange table.

```
INSERT INTO Exchange(currency, rate) VALUES('JJ', 1);
```

Now I use the same sql and the it took **0.3 ~ 0.5** seconds for response. And here is the describe :

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | range  | id_flA        | id_flA  | 3       | NULL            | 4559537 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | E     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | test.P.currency |       1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------+-------------+
```

So the problem (as far as I see), the optimizer trying to use "join buffer". The optimum solution of this problem would be to force optimizer not to use "join buffer". (which I couldn't find how to) or change the "join_buffer_size" value. I solve it by adding "dummy" values to Exchange table (so the optimizer wouldn't use join buffer) but it's not a exact solution, its just a stupid trick to fool mysql.

**Edit :** I researched in mysql forums/bugs about this "join buffer" behavior; then asked about it in [official forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,508230,508300#msg-508300). I am going to fill a bug report about this irrational behavior of optimizer.

Comment: I have read the link on join buffer. It says that extra information on join buffer was implemented from version  5.1.18 onwards. I am using version 5.5.14, so I assume it would be shown. But from all the trials above, under the extra column, I only have `Using where`. The spike I experienced is above 30s for query 4 and 7. I would think there is another reason, else it would be about 3s as per your trial. Thanks for the effort though :)

Comment: did you try changing join_buffer_size in your configuration ? my hypothesis was some of your queries (not all of them) "using join buffer" instead of "using where" clause. in my dataset whole data was evenly distributed (thanks to random) so all my queries eighter used join or where, but since your data is not evenly distributed your problem can be some queries using "join buffer".

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I will look into the join_buffer_size and update you soon.

Comment: I have raised the join_buffer_size from 131072 to 10M. There is no observable reduction in the query times or any reduction in the spikes. To clarify, I don't have any queries showing `using join buffer` in any of the query execution plans. I have also updated the question to show the parameters that I have used. Despite the case, I think you deserve the bounty for the amount of effort you have put in. I will keep this question open for the time being. Thanks.

Comment: I will look it up more when I have time for sure, but after I solved the join buffer issue there were no more "slow" or "spikey" queries for me, if you can edit your question and put queries for user every user actions that would be really nice.

Comment: `P.lat` and `P.lng` are supposed to gradually shrink in range as the query moves from 1 to 10 (see user actions), starting from `P.lat BETWEEN -85 AND 85 AND P.lng BETWEEN -175 AND 175`. You may try `P.floor_area >= 1000` and `P.price * E.rate BETWEEN 100 AND 1000` for other constants. I am not sure whether it would help since our databases are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things:

1. Why are you calculating the product of P.price and E.rate in the SELECT and aliasing as 'ask', then doing the calculation again in the where clause? Should be able to do `AND ask BETWEEN k? and k?` -- **Edit**: **This won't work** due to the way MySQL works. Apparently MySQL evaluates the WHERE clause before any aliases ([sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333134/django-raw-query-calculated-field-in-where-clause)).
2. What kind of index do you have on Exchange.currency and Property.currency? If exchange is a lookup table, maybe you would be better off adding a pivot (linking) table with Property.Id and Exchange.Id
3. The order by floor_area forces MySQL to create a temp table in order to do the sorting correctly, any chance you can do the sorting at the app layer?
4. Adding an index on type column will help as well.

-- **Edit**

Not sure what you mean by the comment `// this and key_buffer_size=0 prevents caching` on the CURDATE where conditional, you can force no sql caching using the 'SQL_NO_CACHE' flag on your [select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) statement.

What I would recommend now that you have removed the ORDER BY, is to update your query statement as follows (Added P alias to columns to reduce any confusion):

```
WHERE P.type ='condominium'
    AND P.floor_area >= k?
    AND P.closing_date >= CURDATE() // No longer necessary with SQL_NO_CACHE
    AND P.lat BETWEEN v? AND v?
    AND P.lng BETWEEN v? AND v?
    AND P.price * E.rate BETWEEN k? AND k?
```

Then add an index to the 'type' column and a composite index on the 'type' and 'floor_area' columns. As you stated, the type column is a low-cardinality column, but the table is large and should help. And even though floor_area appears to be a high-cardinality column, the composite index will help speed up your query times.

You may also want to research if there is a penalty using BETWEEN rather than range operators ( >, <, <= etc.)

Comment: 1. It says Unknown column 'ask' in 'where clause'  2. no index on currency for both tables. I am using myISAM, cannot use foreign key constraint  3. According to the query execution plan, there is no filesort, i supposed no temp table 4. No other index involved in this stage as I am testing on floor_area index.

Comment: I need to know the reasons for the two spikes and solve that. Other query times are more or less acceptable to me for a table of 5 million rows.

Comment: @BenHuh: Sorry, should have asked which engine type you were using. Perhaps posting schema will help. No filesort is good, however the temp table will still happen behind the scenes. Try taking out the ORDER BY for now and see if you get more consistent metrics.

Comment: Yes I do get more consistent query times. But it is generally much slower than previous. See above update. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But it doesn't address the spike in query time issue which I am interested to solve. Based on the extended explain query, the optimiser have no issue with the alias. Nevertheless, I will update the query according to your suggestion. As for the extra composite index, due to the various sort options I  have, I am not able to implement all that without creating an oversized index file. I have previously done a test on `BETWEEN` and find that it doesn't make any significant difference. I will put up a bounty for this once it becomes available.

Answer (score 3):

Try an index on type and floor_area (and possibly closing_date too).

Modify your constants by the exchange rate instead of the price column:

```
P.price between ( k? / E.rate ) and ( k? / E.rate )
```

then try an index on price.

Comment: Your suggestion on using a price index only helps in the filtering process, but does not help in the ordering process, even if I do an `order by ask` it doesn't help in the ordering since the rate is not taken into account. After adopting your suggestion, the optimiser still prefers using fla index. I would tend to think that index is more efficient to be used for ordering in my case. For the specific query above, it is an ordering by floor area. As discussed earlier, a composite index would be considered at a later stage. I am more interested in solving the spike in query times.

Answer (score 2):

I've become a little obsessed with this question; the spike is hard to explain.

Here's what I did:

I re-created your schema, and populated the property table with 4.5 million records, with random values for the numerical and date columns. This almost certainly doesn't match your data - I'm guessing the lat/longs tend to cluster in population areas, the prices around multiples of 10K, and the floor space will be skewed towards lower-end values.

I ran your query with a range of values for lat, long, floorspace and price. With just the index on floor area, I saw the the query plan would ignore the index for some values of floor area. This was presumably because the query analyzer decided the number of records excluded by using the index was too small. However, in re-running the query for a variety of different scenarios, I noticed that the query plan would ignore the index every now and again - can't explain that.

It's always worth running `ANALYZE TABLE` when dealing with this kind of weirdness.

I did get slightly different "explain" results: specifically, the property table select gave 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'. This suggests the index is only used for the where clause, and not to order the results.

This confirms that the most likely explanation of the performance peaks is not related so much to the query engine, but to the way the temporary table is handled, and the requirement to do a filesort. In trying to reproduce this issue, I did notice that response time went up dramatically as the number of records returned from the "where" clause increased - though I didn't see the spikes you've noticed.

I've tried a variety of different indices; using all the keys in the where clause does speed up the  time to retrieve the records matching the where clause, but does nothing for the subsequent order by.

This, once again, suggests it's the performance of the temporary table that's the cause of the spikes. read_rnd_buffer_size would be the obvious thing to look at.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I will look into the read_rnd_buffer_size and update you soon.

Comment: I have raised the read_rnd_buffer_size from 1024M to 1300M. There is no observable reduction in the query times or any reduction in the spikes. Seems that this parameter is already at optimal value.