# Add custom SQL into WHERE clause in Django, without using .raw()

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have a complex django ORM query that I'd really rather not have to convert to raw SQL, because it's a very non-trivial query, I want consistency, I use a number of the ORM features to generate the query, and it's been thoroughly tested as it stands.

I want to add a single filter to the WHERE clause on a datetime field. However, I want to test against the *date* part only, not the time.

Here's a simplified version of my existing query:

```
MyTable.objects.filter(date_field__gte=datetime.now().date())
```

But I've converted the date_field to datetime_field for more precision in some scenarios. In this scenario, however, I still want a date-only comparison. Something like:

```
MyTable.objects.filter(datetime_field__datepartonly__gte=datetime.now().date())
```

In postgres, my database of choice, that's simple:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE(datetime_field) >= ...
```

How can I do this in django, without converting the entire query to raw SQL?

- I tried using F(), but you can only specify field names, not custom SQL.
- I tried using Q(), but same deal.
- I tried Django's SQL functions (Sum, etc), but there are only a few, and it looks like they're designed solely for agreggate queries.
  I tried using an alias, but [you can't use aliases in a WHERE clause, either in Django, or in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333134/django-raw-query-calculated-field-in-where-clause)

**How can I do this in django, without converting the entire query to raw SQL?**

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.raw()` it will return `RawQuerySet` which contains model objects as `QuerySet` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `year`, `month` and `day` fields of the datetime object are available to you, but after testing here it doesn't seem to allow the additional `__gte` application to the field.

This will work:

```
now = datetime.now()
results = MyTable.objects.filter(datetime_field__year=now.year, datetime_field__month=now.month, datetime_field__day=now.day)
```

But doesn't allow gte.

you can always just create a datetime starting at 0:00

```
now = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
results = MyTable.objects.filter(datetime_field__gte=now)
```

Comment: Correct, you can't use __gte with the __year/day/month suffixes, which is important for my use-case. I ran into this issue too, although I didn't mention it above.

Good point -- I can truncate the comparison date in Python. My brain was inverted. This seems to work as expected.